# Heroku CLI error - "cli.Spinner is not a function"

Tags: macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am getting the following message when I try to load a rails console in heroku:

`→ heroku run rails console -a myapp
 ▸    cli.Spinner is not a function`

Output from checking heroku version:

`→ heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.42.47 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/4.29.3-7996295 (amd64-darwin) go1.6
=== Installed Plugins
heroku-apps@1.7.3
heroku-cli-addons@0.3.0
heroku-fork@4.1.2
heroku-git@2.4.5
heroku-local@5.0.1
heroku-orgs@1.0.5
heroku-pg-extras
heroku-pipelines@1.1.3
heroku-run@3.1.1
heroku-spaces@2.1.2
heroku-status@2.1.2`

It has worked for me in the past but now I get this error. I've reinstalled the Heroku CLI using both the Heroku provided package and with `brew install heroku`. I am able to use the CLI for logs with `heroku logs -a myapp`. Any thoughts about what might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by removing your ~/.heroku directory and running heroku update. If you have manually installed plugins you will have to manually reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

This solution actually works in linux. A friend next to me have the issue, and we just remove the ~/.heroku  and run heroku again, because all the files were deleted is just install all the updates.